# Splitbook but with the option to save the nw files worksheet with custom name

Tags: excel, vba

i have in one folder a MASTER file where i have one file with multiple sheets inside.

i am using the below code for the split book,

the macro generate multiple files in the same folder of MASTER file with the name of the sheets of the MASTER file.

I have an issue, when i open the generate files they have all the sheet name as file name...

how can i have same result but for all the new generated files the sheet name as for example Sheet1?

here the code i use for splitbook:

```
Sub Splitbook()

Dim myxWs As Worksheet
Dim myPath As String

Set myxWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each myxWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    myxWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & "\" & myxWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `myxWS` isn't declared anywhere. `Dim myxWs as Worksheet` and `Set myxWs = <your worksheet reference>`.

Comment: first of all thank you, i added Dim myxWs as Worksheet before the other declaratio Dim myPath As String...
Set myxWs = "sheet1" is it correct? where i need to insert it? sorry i am not very familiar with VB

Comment: also the sheets of the Master file has different name and are not standard...maybe on one master the sheets has the name 1, 2, 3, 4 but than next time the sheets of the master has name A, B,C,D...
hope this can help to solve my issue

Comment: @SamuelEverson kindly are you able to help me with my issue please?

Comment: Your set statement is used when assigning an *object* type - so you do it the same as your string - `myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` but put set in front of it like so: `Set myxWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` <~~ this assigns the sheet1 object to `myxWs` which can then be used like you have in the rest of your code. If your sheet names are not standard, you can use the index like so: Set myxWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` - the index number represents the sheet in that number position from the first to last sheet in your workbook.

Comment: If that doesn't resolve your problems, add more information to your question to help better explain what *exactly* you are trying to do :)

Comment: i added the code you suggested but i have same result...  my excel MASTER file has some sheets, with variable names, let say not standard, can be name of person 
sheet1 is named Jon
sheet2 is named Patric
sheet3 is named Henry

so when i run the macro, the macro create 3 files with the name of the sheet, so i will have the file named Jon, Patric and Henry.

Now when i open each of this files, the shit of this files is named in same name of the file instead of Sheet1..

in the end i need the 3 files, Jon Patric and Henry with the sheet inside called Sheet1 instead same name of the file

Comment: if is not clear please let me know

Comment: I'm just gonna repeat this part of my comment... *add more information to your question* - you can do this by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61890479/edit). Most people won't read comments to look for this much info. Also formatting.

Comment: thank you so much, i am not really familiar as you can see from my tag, i edited the code and i removed the crazy comment i made...hope is better...

i would like to add the file in case, is it possible to do it? or at least add some pictures, maybe it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the `Worksheet.Copy` method, The worksheet in your new workbooks you are creating will have all the same name as the copied sheet from your master file.

You can change the name of the first worksheet after you copy like so:

```
For Each myxWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    myxWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & "\" & myxWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Next
```

**NOTE:** [You don't need to use the `Application` qualifyer for `ActiveWorkbook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)) so you could write it as such:

```
For Each myxWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    myxWs.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & "\" & myxWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Next
```

Comment: wow amazing, i really appreciate you time and help  :)  it works very well ...thank you :) where i can learn the macro, sometimes are very useful...i use the power query but i need to learn the macros...if you have any suggestion from where i can start it will be great

Comment: I learn by doing. I find something I want to achieve and I look for solutions online, such as here on SO. Just googling how to do things is a good place to start. And remember it's a very large amount of information to learn so take it step by step. Using the macro recorder is a good way to see what Excel does when you do things. Then google the lines you don't understand and read documentation. If you get stuck, ask a question here! Happy coding!